# In scala, how to create a ClassTag of a specialised class using ClassTag of its generic member?

Tags: scala, template-specialization, scala-reflect

Let's use the common `Array[T]` class as an example:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

{
    val t = implicitly[ClassTag[String]]
    val ts = implicitly[ClassTag[Array[String]]]

    Seq(t, ts).foreach(println)
}
```

this will give the following output:

```
java.lang.String
Array[java.lang.String]
```

It can be observed that type `String` was not erased due to Array having a specialised type member.

My problem is, if the type `String` is not know in compile-time. And you only have a ClassTag of an unknown type `T`, can you still get the specialised ClassTag of Array[T]?

e.g.

```
def arrayClassTagOf[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): ClassTag[Array[T]] = ...
```

such that:

```
arrayClassTagOf[String] == implicitly[ClassTag[Array[String]]
arrayClassTagOf[Int] == implicitly[ClassTag[Array[Int]]
```

etc.

Thanks a lot for your opinion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def arrayClassTagOf[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): ClassTag[Array[T]] = ev.wrap
```

Yes, there is already [`def wrap: ClassTag[Array[T]]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html#wrap:scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[T]]) for this exact job.

Comment: Wow, that function name is deceptive :)

Comment: Non-obvious, certainly, but that's why you look at signatures :)